# Which of this two topology variants looks better to you?

Tags: mesh, topology

I just need to clarify it for myself and appreciate any help and explanation. Each topology seems OK, but may be quad based is somehow better? It certainly looks better to me. (see topology_question.jpg)
[image: topology]

Comment: you could even have a big ngon that fill the whole surface, as long as it doesn't cause any artifact in render...

Comment: I agree about n-gons. If you stay in Blender they are sometimes easier to work with - for example they often work better with bevels than a flat surface that has edges with very sharp corners ending  on the lines being bevelled. I used to avoid them, but now I often use them and they save a lot of time and give good results in certain situations.

Comment: Thank you. But i need to stay close to turbosquid requirements. So I need to avoid n-gones, i guess.

Comment: Oh, in that case, yes, avoid n-gons.

Comment: Down to Both, Left or  Right, Neither is gone.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the topology needs to be overly complicated. I would go for something like this: 
[image]

I would also consider this being generous with poly count because this is a shape that can be smoothed with surface subdivision so there is probably no real need to have it very dense.

If I buy a model I am certainly not looking for complicated topology as in the examples, but I want to be able to edit it quickly(I don't want to do anything with it ideally, but I like to see the possibility, if I ever need to edit it) meaning I want loop and ring selection and manipulation tools to work. This way I can select edge rings, checker deselect every other one and multi select loops and dissolve them if I want lower resolution, or just to use Subsurf modifier to make it smoother. It's also easier to modify shapes and forms this way and create/recreate some specific UV maps if I happen to need something different than what comes with the model.

Comment: Thank you. My main purpose was to connect 40 verts cylinder-like mesh (because I have other parts of mesh with 40 verts cylinder-like objects) with box, and still preserve ability for an artist to subdivide crucial parts of model. I don't know how to add a picture :-(

Comment: Here it is https://imgur.com/rqpkKi5 Oh, my, I guess i just forgot to decrease vertex count in that cylinder-like object.

Comment: In any case, my answer would still be that it's probably best to make nice and tidy loops around the hole that transition smoothly to the corners and not to have any unnecessary vertices on the flat surface. Easier to work with, easier to edit... What if I need to make the circle bigger? I could select the face rings and scale them, but then the extra vertices there would get in the way... The simpler, the better.